# Swift: Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report

Tags: swift, mapkit, xcode15, ios17

**Hello, im having trouble with XCode 15. This is my full code of this part:**

```
struct ExploreView: View {
    @State private var cameraPosition: MapCameraPosition = .region(.userRegion)
    @State private var searchText = ""
    @State private var results = [MKMapItem]()
    @State private var mapSelection: MKMapItem?
    @State private var showDetails = false
    @State private var getDirections = false
    
    @State var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: .init(latitude: 37.334_900,longitude: -122.009_020),
        span: .init(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2)
    )
    
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Map(coordinateRegion: $region, showsUserLocation: true, userTrackingMode: .constant(.follow))
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    .onAppear {
                        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
                    }
                    
                    ForEach(results, id: \.self) { item in
                        let placemark = item.placemark
                        Marker(placemark.name ?? "", coordinate: placemark.coordinate)
                    }
                }
                .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
                    TextField("Suche beispielsweise nach \"Kebab\"", text: $searchText)
                        .cornerRadius(12)
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .padding(12)
                        .background(.thinMaterial)
                        .padding()
                        .shadow(radius: 10)
                }
                .onSubmit(of: .text) {
                    Task { await searchPlaces() }
                }
                .onChange(of: mapSelection, { oldValue, newValue in
                    showDetails = newValue != nil
                })
                .sheet(isPresented: $showDetails, content: {
                    LocationDeatilsView(mapSelection: $mapSelection, show: $showDetails, getDirections: $getDirections)
                        .presentationDetents([.height(340)])
                        .presentationBackgroundInteraction(.enabled(upThrough: .height(340)))
                        .presentationCornerRadius(12)
                })
                .mapControls {
                    MapCompass()
                    MapPitchToggle()
                    MapUserLocationButton()
                }
            }
            .onAppear() {
                Task { await searchKebab() }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Ort des Dönermannes", displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
```

The ForEach loop (ForEach(results, id: .self) { item in...) causes the issue. By removing the last line of the loop (Marker(...)) the code works perfectly fine. If you need to know this, i have some extensions for the view:

```
extension ExploreView {
    func searchPlaces() async {
        let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchText
        request.region = .userRegion
        
        let results = try? await MKLocalSearch(request: request).start()
        self.results = results?.mapItems ?? []
    }
    
    func searchKebab() async {
        let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = "Kebab"
        request.region = .userRegion
        
        searchText = "Kebab"
        
        let results = try? await MKLocalSearch(request: request).start()
        self.results = results?.mapItems ?? []
    }
}

extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {
    static var userLocation: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        return .init(latitude: 53.62029035596979, longitude: 9.862939156850185)
    }
}

extension MKCoordinateRegion {
    static var userRegion: MKCoordinateRegion {
        return .init(center: .userLocation,
                     latitudinalMeters: 10000,
                     longitudinalMeters: 10000)
    }
}
```

I get the Message in the line with "var body: some View{...}"Of course i've already checked other posts and googled it... But nothing works :/
**Thank you so much! :)**

Comment: `placemark.location.coordinate`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Unfortunately that does not work... But thanks

Comment: It is a typo, comment out section until it becomes obvious

Comment: @loremipsum I've already tried that and noticed, the problematic line is this one: Marker(placemark.name ?? "", coordinate: placemark.coordinate)

But i don't know whats wrong with it...

Comment: Make sure coordinate is not optional. Do you have another struct called Marker?

Comment: @loremipsum oh well, that seems to be it! No, i don't have another struct, because i have this code from a YouTube Video where everything works. Right-Clicking on "Marker" and selecting "Jump to Definition" opens like a "?", so i definitely have to fix that.

But do you have a short idea for such a struct? Im not that good at programming in swift, so i don't really know, how to do this... I had this Balloon-type Marker in my mind, same as you would get when tapping and holding a spot on Apples "Maps" app... Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
if let name = item.placemark.name, let coordinate = item.placemark.coordinate {

    Marker(name, coordinate: coordinate)

 }
```

You might have to add an `else` with an alternate view if either the name or the coordinate is `nil`